# create element using array foreach()

Tags: arrays, foreach

```
var grid = document.getElementById("grid");
const calendar = [
  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,
  23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,
];
calendar.forEach(myFunction);
function myFunction(value) {
  let div = document.createElement("div");
  div.classList.add("grid-item");
  div.innerHTML = value;
  grid.appendChild(div);
}
```

Here is my codes. I want to create single "div" Element per 500ms for all array items.
How do I do this.
I tried with "setTimeout", but it doesn't work.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by "tried with setTimeout". That isn't in your example. Show how you tried with it. Your question needs to include a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this code ?

```
var grid = document.getElementById("grid");
const calendar = [
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,
    23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,
];

function appendChildInGrid(index) {
    console.log(calendar[index]);
    if (index < calendar.length) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            let value = calendar[index];
            let div = document.createElement("div");
            div.classList.add("grid-item");
            div.innerHTML = value;
            grid.appendChild(div);

            index++;
            appendChildInGrid(i);
        }, 500);
    }
}

appendChildInGrid(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Instead of setTimeout use busy waiting function

```js
const wait = (milliseconds) => {
  var dt = new Date();
    while ((new Date()) - dt <= milliseconds) { /* Do nothing */ }
}

wait(2000)
```